# Как проверить сайт на кросс-браузерность?

Tags: вёрстка, crossbrowsertesting

Здравствуйте! Подскажите на каких сервисах можно проверить только сверстанный сайт на кросс-браузерность. В особенности можно ли как то проверить работу сайта в safari, не имея apple устройств под рукой

Comment: Поставьте себе виртуалку с макосью

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/the-7-cross-browser-testing-tools-you-need-in-2016/